# Date Picker Styling Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

I'm working on a sitecore project where i'm using **WFFM** (Web Forms For Marketers), I have a form and would like to change the styling of a date picker. By default it appears with -'s. I ant /'s.

One way would be:

```
$('.scfDatePickerTextBox').val().replace(/-/g,'/')
```

Theres no option to change the styles? that I know of? Any help guidance would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

When using WFFM as your forms builder i think it is not possible to style the dateformat.
When adding a date field, it always shows up as three droplists:
see this image: http://content.screencast.com/users/MoonCrawler/folders/Jing/media/627a9a76-de8d-4ad7-9097-81e21d38f54c/2013-01-30_1658.png

If you want to change styles (display) assign different css class. if your date is displayed with -'s  in stead of /'s then i think you are using a custom form, you should be able configure the output of the date via the code behind file.

if this does not help, please provide sitecore version, WFFM version and type of form used.